# Infinite scrolling catches on vigorous scrolling/swiping in google chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, scroll

I have an infinite scroll box. There is a list of items and as the list scrolls up, items are appended from the bottom, and vice versa for scrolling down. When the user scrolls down or up normally, it works as expected. When they scroll with a laptop trackpad or on a screen with enough force, then the scroll bar reaches the top and the user needs to scroll down again for it work. Is there a way to get around this?

Here's a [codepen link](https://codepen.io/user8176/pen/bGzeZJx?editors=1111) to what I'm trying to do. Seems like it won't scroll down on load in codepen (this is not the problem so please ignore), please scroll down a bit for it to work. I can produce the described behavior when I use a laptop trackpad or touch screen, I swipe down so the list moves upwards. Hope this wasn't confusing - basically I want the scroll bar to never reach the top no matter how hard a user scrolls/swipes.

```
let container = document.querySelector('.calendar-container')
let calendar = document.querySelector('.calendar')

container.addEventListener('scroll', function (event) {

  const factor = container.scrollTop / (container.scrollHeight - container.offsetHeight);
  if(factor < 0.4) {
      let move = calendar.querySelector(':last-child')
      move.remove();
      calendar.prepend(move);
  } else if(factor > 0.6) {
      let move = calendar.querySelector(':first-child')
      move.remove();
      calendar.append(move);
  }

});

calendar.scroll(0,100);
```

As per the comments, right now this only an issue in chrome

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the issue you are describing. I'm on Windows 11 Firefox and I have a mouse with a inertial flywheel that allows me to scroll very fast. No problems. My laptop has a touchscreen and I tried it there too, again no real issues.

Comment: @ChrisBarr, thanks for checking this. I have been doing this in chrome. When I switch to firefox I am also unable to reproduce. I wonder what makes chrome do this.

Comment: Hmm, yep I can get that to happen in Chrome as well.  My mouse scrollwheel works fine and I can never get to the end, but with my laptop touchscreen I can flick it and go to the end, it pauses a bit, and then keeps scrolling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found a hacky solution but will be open to see others if anyone else has a better fix, just add this to the end of the scroll event

```
  if (document.querySelector('.calendar-container').scrollTop < 10) {
      document.querySelector('.calendar-container').scroll(0,150)
   }
```

});

```js
let container = document.querySelector('.calendar-container')
let calendar = document.querySelector('.calendar')

container.addEventListener('scroll', function(event) {

  const factor = container.scrollTop / (container.scrollHeight - container.offsetHeight);
  if (factor < 0.4) {
    let move = calendar.querySelector(':last-child')
    move.remove();
    calendar.prepend(move);
  } else if (factor > 0.6) {
    let move = calendar.querySelector(':first-child')
    move.remove();
    calendar.append(move);
  }
  if (document.querySelector('.calendar-container').scrollTop < 10) {
    document.querySelector('.calendar-container').scroll(0, 150)
  }
});

calendar.scroll(0, 100);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.calendar-container {
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  /* width: 0px;
  background: transparent;  */
}

.calendar {
  padding: 0;
}

.calendar-container li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80%;
  order: 5;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 1px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #eee;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="calendar-container">

    <ul class="calendar">

      <li class="calendar-hour" data-date="" data-hour="0"></li>
      <li class="calendar-hour" data-date="" data-hour="1"></li>
      <li class="calendar-hour" data-date="" data-hour="2"></li>
      <li class="calendar-hour" data-date="" data-hour="3"></li>
      <li class="calendar-hour" data-date="" data-hour="4"></li>
      <li class="calendar-hour" data-date="" data-hour="5"></li>
      <li class="calendar-hour" data-date="" data-hour="6"></li>
      <li class="calendar-hour" data-date="" data-hour="7"></li>
      <li class="calendar-hour" data-date="" data-hour="8"></li>
      <li class="calendar-hour" data-date="" data-hour="9"></li>
      <li class="calendar-hour" data-date="" data-hour="10"></li>
      <li class="calendar-hour" data-date="" data-hour="11"></li>
      <li class="calendar-hour" data-date="" data-hour="12"></li>
      <li class="calendar-hour" data-date="" data-hour="13"></li>
      <li class="calendar-hour" data-date="" data-hour="14"></li>
      <li class="calendar-hour" data-date="" data-hour="15"></li>
      <li class="calendar-hour" data-date="" data-hour="16"></li>
      <li class="calendar-hour" data-date="" data-hour="17"></li>
      <li class="calendar-hour" data-date="" data-hour="18"></li>
      <li class="calendar-hour" data-date="" data-hour="19"></li>
      <li class="calendar-hour" data-date="" data-hour="20"></li>
      <li class="calendar-hour" data-date="" data-hour="21"></li>
      <li class="calendar-hour" data-date="" data-hour="22"></li>
      <li class="calendar-hour" data-date="" data-hour="23"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```